# Please help me for using memcpy() in C

Tags: c, string, hex, memcpy, short

I have the following code:

```
void main()
{
    char tmp[3]= "AB";
    short k;
    memcpy(&k,tmp,2);
    printf("%x\n", k);
}
```

In ASCII, the hex value of char 'A' is 41 and the hex value of char 'B' is 42.  Why is the result of this program 4241? I think the correct result is 4142.

Comment: lookup endianness.....(big endian, little endian)

Comment: Because thats how an int is stored in the memory (in reverse order). so you need to write "BA".

Comment: Use `int main(void)`, not `void main()` (unless you're using an embedded system).  If your textbook or tutorial told you to write `void main()`, you need to get a better one.

Answer (score 4):

You are apparently running this on a "little-endian" machine, where the least significant byte comes first. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness.

Answer (score 1):

Your platform stores less significant bytes of a number at smaller memory addresses, and more significant bytes at higher memory addresses. Such platforms are called *little-endian* platforms.

However, when you print a number the more significant digits are printed first while the less significant digits are printed later (which is how our everyday numeric notation works). For this reason the result looks "reversed" compared to the way it is stored in memory on a little-endian platform.

If you compile and run the same program on a *big-endian* platform, the output should be `4142` (assuming a platform with 2-byte `short`).

P.S. One can argue that the "problem" in this case is the "weirdness" of our everyday numerical notation: we write numbers so that the significance of their digits increase in right-to-left direction. This appears to be inconsistent in the context of societies that write and read in left-to-right direction. In other words, it in not the little-endian memory that is reversed. It is the way we write numbers that is reversed.

Comment: The "weirdness" is because we got our numbers from the arabs, who write right-to-left, so for them it's consistently little-endian. (Just in case any reader doesn't know yet.)

Comment: i have one more question: why is the following codes, the result still is "AB"? 
void main() 
{ 
char tmp[3]= "AB"; char tmp2[3]; 
memcpy(tmp2,tmp,3); 
printf("%s\n", tmp2);
 }

Comment: @jackson: Why shouldn't it be? Note, the memory content in all of your examples is `"AB"`. It is not changed in any way by `memcpy`. The only case when it something appears to be reversed is when you attempt to `printf` it *as an integer*. And the only thing that is "reversed" is the output on the screen. The memory still contains `"AB"`. If you `printf` the same memory as string (not as integer), you will see `"AB"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your system is little-endian.  That means that a `short` (16-bit integer) is stored with the least significant byte first, followed by the most significant byte.

The same goes for larger integers.  The following code would result in "44434241".

```
void main() 
{ 
    char tmp[5]= "ABCD"; 
    int k; 
    memcpy(&k,tmp,4); 
    printf("%x\n", k); 
}
```

Comment: i have one more question: why is the following codes, the result still is "AB"?

void main()
{
    char tmp[3]= "AB";
    char tmp2[3];
    memcpy(tmp2,tmp,3);
    printf("%s\n", tmp2);
}

Comment: `memcpy` copies the memory byte for byte without changing the order.  It's not `memcpy` that gives you the result `4241`.  It's the way the system interprets the byts when read it as a `short`